# Large Gap Between Appendix Title and Figure

Tags: spacing, graphics, appendix

I am constructing the appendix and there is a large gap between the title of the appendix and the figure I would like to attach. Below is my code and a screenshot that further depicts the problem. In case the pictures are not clear, there is about a 1.5 page gap between the title of the appendix ("Appendix A: Overview") and the figure, which is not optimal.

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need any more information!

```
 \documentclass[pmlr,twocolumn,10pt]{jmlr} % W&CP article
 
 \let\SUP\textsuperscript

\usepackage{tabto}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[load-configurations=version-1]{siunitx} % newer version 
\newcommand{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}% remove this in your real article
\newcommand{\equal}[1]{{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\thanks{#1}}}

% Customized Tabs
\newcommand\mytab{\hspace{10mm} \hspace{-5cm}}

 % Define an unnumbered theorem just for this sample document for
 % illustrative purposes:
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theorempostheader{:}
\theoremsep{\newline}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
\end{keywords}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro} 

\section{Related Works}
\label{sec:RelatedWorks}

\section{Dataset, Preprocessing, and Annotations}
\label{sec:Dataset+Preprocessing+Annotations}

\paragraph{Dataset}
\label{sec:Dataset}  

% Figure 1 - Example Sequences
\begin{figure*}[h!]
\label{fig:fig1}
\centering 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.35]{Figure-1.png}
\caption{Example Sequences}
\end{figure*}

\paragraph{Preprocessing}
\label{sec:Preprocessing}

\paragraph{Annotations}
\label{sec:Annotations}

\section{Methodology}
\label{sec:Methodology}  

\section{Results}
\label{sec:Results}  

%% Conclusion + Future Work %%
\section{Conclusion and Future Work} 

\clearpage
\appendix

% Appendix A
% Figure 2 - Overview
\section{Overview}
\label{fig:fig2}
\begin{figure*}[!htbp]
\centering 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.14]{Overview.png}
\caption{Overview}
\end{figure*}

\newpage 

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: figure* always goes on the next page, as does \twocolumn[...].  OTOH, you can put \appendix and \section in a \onecolumn area and not notice the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\onecolumn` after the `\appendix` to use the full page right there, instead of the `figure*`going to the next page.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[pmlr,twocolumn,10pt]{jmlr} % W&CP article
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\begin{document}    

    \section{Introduction}
    \label{sec:intro} 
    
    \section{Related Works}
    \label{sec:RelatedWorks}
    
    \section{Dataset, Preprocessing, and Annotations}
    \label{sec:Dataset+Preprocessing+Annotations}
    
    \section{Methodology}
    \label{sec:Methodology}     
    \kant[1]
    
    \section{Results}
    \label{sec:Results}  
    \kant[9]
    
    \newpage
    \section{Conclusion and Future Work} 
    \kant[11]
    \clearpage
    
    \appendix
    \onecolumn % added <<<<<<<<
    % Appendix A
    % Figure 2 - Overview
    \section{Overview}

    \label{fig:fig2}
    \begin{figure*}[!htbp]
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Overview}
    \end{figure*}
    
\end{document}
```